Nux 3 sidebase auth with AppleProvider fix redirect
Is there a way to successfully log in with the AppleProvider using sidebase auth (Next Auth).
Here is my nuxt.config.ts
auth: {
    baseURL: process.env.AUTH_ORIGIN,
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    provider: {
      type: 'authjs'
    },
    session: {
      enableRefreshPeriodically: false,
      enableRefreshOnWindowFocus: true
    }
  },

and inside my NuxtAuthHandler
 providers: [
    // @ts-expect-error You need to use .default here for it to work during SSR. May be fixed via Vite at some point
    AppleProvider.default({
      clientId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.APPLE_SECRET
    }),
 ]

I have managed to successfully log in with GoogleProvider with GithubProvider and with CredentialsProvider.
With this configuration, after submitting all the required data during login with Apple, it redirects back to the login page without logging in the user. The only error I'm seeing in the console is "PKCE code_verifier cookie was missing."
so i have added this data to my NuxtAuthHandler:
cookies: {
    pkceCodeVerifier: {
      name: "next-auth.pkce.code_verifier",
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
      },
    },
  },

And i was able to successfully log in. But the problem is that i am always redirect back to the / page. So my question is, is there a better way to log in with AppleProvider or is there a way to fix this redirect after login to the / page ?
I have tried to change path but that not fix the problem, It redirects back to the login page without logging in the user.
